# C++ custom allocator

Tags: c++, templates, allocator

Hi I have written a custom allocator with the help of some resources. It works fine for std::vector, list . However for std::unordered_map the constructor gets called twice . I am not why. Can someone please help me understand the static initialization that is happening. Here's the code

File:helper.h

```
template<typename T>
class helper
{
 static const size_t init_size = 12; // 0xF4240 max number of entries in the data structure
public:
      helper() :
      alloc_size(
      sizeof(link) > sizeof(T) ?
      init_size * sizeof(link) : init_size * sizeof(T)), offset(
      sizeof(link) > sizeof(T) ? sizeof(link) : sizeof(T))
  {
       std::cout <<"Initial allocation done" << " I value : " << i << std::endl;
   }


};
```

File: main.cpp

```
int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<long,long,hash<long>, equal_to<long> , myallocator<pair<const long,long> > >            my_map;
}
```

calling it that way makes the **helper** constrcutor get called twiced in the program. It doesn'y happen like that for vector. Is there something i am not understanding with regards to template initialization. Please help

Comment: --1: "the constrcutor"?  Which one?  Please post a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve -- one that actually compiles.  Please include both what output you expect, and what you got, **exactly**.  Have you read the "how to ask a question" help pages?  They should walk you through it.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. i have made the changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Containers may create allocators not only for the type you provided, but also for different types via `rebind`. This is what apparently happens in your case. You didn't provide enough code so others can compile and check it, but you can add this in the constructor of `helper`:

```
std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
```

This works in GCC and Clang and will show the template parameters the function/class was instantiated with.

Comment: thanks for the suggetion. I tried putting that in the helper constructor and i get the following . it gets called with with T = std::__detail::_Hash_node_base* and then it gets called with T = std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<const long unsigned int, long unsigned int> . Why does it do that? Thanks